# ItemAdding event on list item to target a specific custom list

Tags: event-handlers, list-item

I have an ItemAdding event handler created and targeted to a Custom List. The event receiver seems to be firing on all custom list on the site. I wonder if I should target it to a specific custom list. Is this possible? or should I just leave it like it is now? If it's possible, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Navigate to corresponding Elements.xml, and you will notice `Receivers` element with `ListTemplateId` attribute, like this:

```
<Receivers ListTemplateId="100">
   ...
</Receivers>
```

What you need is to use `ListUrl` attribute instead, and point it to the specific list using provided url.

There is a how-to on this on MSDN:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398052.aspx

Basic example:

```
<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/Test">
   ...
</Receivers>
```

Full schema of Receivers element could be found in [Receivers Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms431081.aspx) MSDN reference article.

Also, the binding could be performed programmatically (usually in FeatureActivated receiver), using [SPList.EventReceivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.eventreceivers.aspx) collection.

Comment: ListUrl works only if feature has Scope=”Web”. In case the feature has Scope=”Site”, event receiver is fired for every list, ListUrl is ignored.